# Unity Playmode low fps on Macbook m1

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, apple-m1

I've have found a problem running unity(ver. 2019.4.34f1 and 2021.2.8f1) on my MacBook m1 chip. Whenever I run Playmode *while having Scene and Game tab open at the same time* I get only around 30fps which is very strange running on m1 chip. But When I *closed the Scene tab and ONLY having the Game tab open*, the fps jump to 400fps+.

I have:

- installed mono, .Net Arm64
- Default Unity Configuration

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has to do with a default setting on a LapTop to save power. Try changing the **interaction mode** under Edit/Preferences/General.

> Interaction Mode  Specifies how long the Editor can idle before it
> updates. After one frame finishes, the Editor waits up to the
> specified amount of time before the next frame begins.
>
> This allows you to throttle Editor performance, and reduce consumption
> of CPU resources and power.
>
> For example, if you want to test the Editor’s performance, set this
> property to No Throttling. If you want to conserve power (for example,
> to prolong battery life on a laptop computer), set this property to
> one of the throttled modes.
>
> In throttled modes, the Editor stops idling if you interact with it
> (for example, by panning in the Scene view).
>
> Note: In Play mode, Unity ignores any throttling that you apply using
> this preference. The editor updates as fast as possible unless you
> enable the VSync option in the Game view, or set
> Application.targetFrameRate to a value other than –1.
> [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Preferences.html)